# React.useReducer() is throwing TS2769: No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-reducer

Newish to TS. I have a very simple demo app that uses the `useReducer()` hook to manage the `selected` state of items in a list. I thought I did a good job of making the reducer type safe but when I call the `useReducer()` hook I get the `TS2769: No overload matches this call` error. I will list the contents of the reducer file, the component which calls `useReducer()` and then the exact error text, and a sandbox link:

Here is my reducer file:

```
// src/Components/List/Reducer.ts
export type ListAction = {
    type: 'TOGGLE_SELECTED'
    index: number
}

export type ListItemState = {
    name: string
    color: string
    selected: boolean
}

const reducer = (state: ListItemState[], action: ListAction): ListItemState[] => {
    const {index, type} = action
    switch(type) {
        case 'TOGGLE_SELECTED':
            const item = state[index]
            const newState = state.slice()
            newState[index] = {...item, selected: !item.selected}
            return newState
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default reducer
```

Here is the component which calls `useReducer()`:

```
//src/Components/List/List.tsx
import React, {useReducer} from "react";
import Reducer, {ListItemState} from "./Reducer";
import InitialState from "./InitialState";
import ListItem from "../ListItem/ListItem";
import SelectedItems from "../SelectedItems/SelectedItems";
import "./List.css";

const List = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, InitialState);
    const selected = state
        .filter((item: ListItemState) => item.selected)
        .map((selected: ListItemState) => selected.name);
    return (
        <>
            <SelectedItems items={selected} />
            <ul className="List">
                {state.map((item: ListItemState, index: number) => (
                    <ListItem {...item} key={item.name} index={index} dispatch={dispatch} />
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
};

export default List
```

Here is the exact error text:

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in src/Components/List/List.tsx:10:31

TS2769: No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(state: ListItemState[], action: ListAction) => ListItemState[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction'.
Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: ListItemState[], action: ListAction) => ListItemState[], initialState: ListItemState[], initializer?: undefined): [...]', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ListItemState[]'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ListItemState'.
8 |
9 | const List = () => {

> 10 |     const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, InitialState);
> |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 11 |     const selected = state
> 12 |         .filter((item: ListItemState) => item.selected)
> 13 |         .map((selected: ListItemState) => selected.name);

Comment: Your initial state is `string[]`, but your reducer expects `ListItemState[]`.

Comment: As an aside, the Reducer.tsx file in your sandbox is empty.

Comment: Thanks @AKX. The initial state is an array of objects like this: `[{name: 'foo', color: 'red' selected: false}]`.

Comment: Well, no, it's not in your example ;-)

Comment: @AKX The initial state is the `items` exported from `src/Components/List/InitialState`. If I console that variable it is an array of objects. I understand that TS _thinks_ it's an array of strings but it doesn't appear so. What am I missing? Thank you. Updated link: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-ride-j0y9y4

Comment: It's that `reduce` pyramid that's not properly typed – when in doubt, don't use `reduce`, TS or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a type-safe simplification of your code in a single file. The `reduce` pyramid you had in your `InitialState` file is throwing TS off.

In other words, your reducer and state are fine, it's just that your initial data indeed wasn't soundly typed.

[Sandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-bash-nq6go5?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

function getInitialState(): ListItemState[] {
  const sizes = ["tiny", "small", "medium", "large", "huge"];
  const colors = ["blue", "green", "orange", "red", "purple"];
  const fruits = ["apple", "banana", "watermelon"];
  const items = [];
  for (const size of sizes) {
    for (const color of colors) {
      for (const fruit of fruits) {
        items.push({
          name: `${size} ${color} ${fruit}`,
          color,
          selected: false
        });
      }
    }
  }
  return items;
}
type ListAction = {
  type: "TOGGLE_SELECTED";
  index: number;
};

type ListItemState = {
  name: string;
  color: string;
  selected: boolean;
};

function reducer(state: ListItemState[], action: ListAction): ListItemState[] {
  const { index, type } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case "TOGGLE_SELECTED":
      const item = state[index];
      const newState = [...state];
      newState[index] = { ...item, selected: !item.selected };
      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function List() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, null, getInitialState);
  const selected = state
    .filter(({ selected }) => selected)
    .map(({ name }) => name);
  return (
    <>
      {JSON.stringify(selected)}
      <div>
        {state.map(({ name, color }, index) => (
          <button
            key={name}
            onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_SELECTED", index })}
            style={{ color }}
          >
            {name}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <List />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: AKX  You are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you!

Comment: @NeilGirardi Glad I could help! As an aside, whenever you find yourself typing the dreaded trigram `any` in TypeScript, lean back and take a deep breath and reconsider your life choices, then rewrite what you're doing without `any`. 99% of the time, `any` is a code _stench_.

Comment: indeed! I recently had a similar TS issue and that code also used Array.prototype.reduce. Is there a trick to using reduce with TS? Does one generally have to avoid reduce when using TS?

Comment: Well, I'd say generally avoid `reduce`, in both TS and JS. It usually leads to unreadable and complex code.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @akx answer and trying his excellent solution I decided to go back and attempt the original reduce "pyramid" solution. It turned out to be fairly straight forward. After converting the `items` variable to a function I had make the return type of that function `ListItemState[]`, **and** I also had to make `ListItemState[]` the type of the accumulator (ie previous) value of *both* of the `Array.prototype.reduce()` callbacks:

```
const getInitialState = (): ListItemState[] => sizes.reduce(
    (items: ListItemState[], size: string) => [
        ...items,
        ...fruits.reduce(
            (acc: ListItemState[], fruit: string) => [
                ...acc,
                ...colors.reduce(
                    (acc: any[], color: string) => [
                        ...acc,
                        {
                            name: `${size} ${color} ${fruit}`,
                            color
                        }
                    ],
                    []
                )
            ],
            []
        )
    ],
    []
);
```

Comment: This is also a lot less efficient, mind, since you're taking tons and tons of array copies. Sometimes a for loop is better...

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is "fairly straight forward"... It's 10 times easier to look at the loop to understand what's going on  and as @AKX mentioned, it's less efficient. But yes, you can do it using nested reduces, just don't hope that others will be able to grok it.

Comment: @JuanMendes duly noted. I wanted to get this to work with the reduce calls because I recently ran into a similar issue doing a JS -> TS conversion on a file with some calls to `Array.prototype.reduce()`. Therefore, I wanted to figure out how to make `.reduce()` work with TS. I think what I learned it that it may not be enough to type the return value of the function calling `.reduce`. You may need to type the `.reduce()` callback. And if you pass an empty array or an empty object as the optional initial `.reduce()` values, you may need to type those as well.

Comment: It is pretty cool I just disagreed with the "fairly straightforward" 